# Merging two tables without losing data

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get this :

Table 1 :

| id | type |
| --- | --- |
| x1 | p1 |
| x2 | p1 |
| x3 | g1 |

Table 2 :

| id | type |
| --- | --- |
| x1 | p1 |
| x2 | p1 |

I need to SELECT a the first table with all values but if values from table 2 appear in table 1 add new column to table 1 with indication that is duplication.

Table 1 :

| id | type | duplicate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x1 | p1 | 1 |
| x2 | p1 | 1 |
| x3 | g1 | 0 |

Answer (score 0):

We can try the following left join plus aggregation approach:

```sql
SELECT t1.id, t1.type, IF(COUNT(t2.id) > 0, 1, 0) AS duplicate
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.id = t1.id AND t2.type = t1.type
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.type
ORDER BY t1.id, t1.type;
```

Here is a working [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=71a174314b899d7180bc4b1bbf191087) showing that the above logic is working.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!
im getting this on the IF part :  an expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected

Comment: I don't think you are running my code.  My usage of `IF()` should be valid.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen If a record is in t2 but not in t1 wouldn't you get ```null | null | 0``` as a result?

Comment: @Natrium The `COUNT()` function _always_ returns an integer value.  `COUNT(NULL)` is zero.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen But t1.id and t1.type in the SELECT would be null in that case, I think.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I reread the question, and OP states they need to select from table1, so my argument might not be valid.

Comment: @Natrium I just added a demo link to my answer, the code is fine.  The OP most likely changed my code or else perhaps did not copy correctly.